# How to remove the border of a ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I have a `DataTemplateSelector` like this:

```
Public Class TestTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector

    Public Property Template1 As DataTemplate
    Public Property Template2 As DataTemplate

    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
        Dim selector As Integer

        If (item Is Nothing) OrElse TypeOf item IsNot String Then
            Return MyBase.SelectTemplate(item, container)
        End If

        If Not Integer.TryParse(CType(item, String), selector) Then
            Return MyBase.SelectTemplate(item, container)
        End If

        Select Case selector
            Case 1
                Return Me.Template1
            Case 2
                Return Me.Template2
            Case Else
                Return MyBase.SelectTemplate(item, container)
        End Select
    End Function

End Class
```

I define it in the `Resources` of a `Window` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <TextBox Text="Template 1" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
        <TextBox Text="Template 2" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:TestTemplateSelector x:Key="sel"
                                Template1="{StaticResource Template1}"
                                Template2="{StaticResource Template2}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And I use it in the same `Window` like this:

```
<ContentControl Margin="5"
                Content="2"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource sel}" />
```

If I switch the `Content` of the `ContentControl` between 1 and 2 it shows the corresponding templates, but I always see a gray border around the `ContentControl`.

Setting the `BorderBrush` of the `ContentControl` to `Transparent` and/or setting the `BorderThickness` to 0 doesn't remove the border.

How can I get rid of this border?

Here's a screenshot of the whole window:

[image]

Comment: A `ContentControl` should not have a border. In which other controls is it nested? Chances are it is just a parent control that causes the border.

Comment: No other control, it's the content of my test window, there's not even a grid around it.

Comment: Can you attach an image that shows the whole view including the window and border?

Comment: Added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: What happens if you place any other Control in there, e.g. a `Grid`? Is the border sill there?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no border by default. You may have an implicit `Style` somewhere that adds it.

Try to set the `BorderThickness` property to `0`:

```
<ContentControl Margin="5"
                BorderThickness="0"
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                Content="2"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource sel}" />
```

Or set the `Template` property to a `ControlTemplate` without a `Border`:

```
<ContentControl Margin="5"
                Content="2"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource sel}">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```